# An app which has complete control of the device

Tags: android

I would like to create an app which is preinstalled on a device and has complete control of it (no way to exit it), this is for devices handed out for a specific purpose. It will have some pages/navigation as well as the ability to run certain whitelisted apps.

Is there anything out there helping with this, or would this kind of an app have to be a custom build of Android? Thanks.

Comment: If you remove the "ability to run certain whitelisted apps" bit, Android 5.0+ has a kiosk mode. That is designed for a single app, though, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

To have complete control over the device you would need a custom operating system. I don't think it is possible to do what you are asking for with an app

Answer (score 1):

The way was in progress to implement this was with a custom compiled OS that signed a launcher with the key provided by the hardware vendor.

You can certainly fake most of this with your own launcher but to get it to be the system default launcher you need to have the vendor key I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

There are apps that donot do exactly what you want but achieve something similar to that. [App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) is one such app. It blocks the specific app view from the user until he enters the pin. The user will have to set Device administrator properties for such an app usually but if you are planning it as preinstalled then that can also be handled.

Comment: Thanks that looks promising